# navbar active link not working with real link

Tags: html, jquery, flask, navbar

I have been tried all day to make the link active when I click on it but it only works with a `href` that is "fake" but not with my `href`. In the example code, it works for `Research` but not for `Upload`.

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('uploader.upload') }}">Upload</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Research</a>
</li>
```

Comment: It works for 'Research' because that doesn't cause the page to be unloaded and transferred to a new URL. If you want to keep the active state of a link for the given page then you'd be best to do it server side.

Comment: You *are* aware that "active" means "Has the pointer pointing at it and the mouse button pressed down or is focused and has the enter key pressed down" and **not** "has an href attribute that matches what is in the address bar"?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I only started to learn flask yesterday, I am not sure what you mean by "If you want to keep the active state of a link for the given page then you'd be best to do it server side". Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

ended up working, turned out jquery and bootstrap were not in sync

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Hazen</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
<div class="navbar-nav">
{% if not current_user.is_anonymous %}

<a class="nav-item nav-link {% if display_page=='index' %} active{% 
endif %}" class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.user', 
username=current_user.username) }}">Dashboard</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link {% if display_page=='upload' %} active{% 
endif %}" href="{{ url_for('uploader.upload') }}">Upload</a>
{% endif %}
{% if current_user.is_anonymous %}

<a class="nav-item nav-link"  href="{{ url_for('auth.login') 
}}">Login</a>

{% else %}

<a class="nav-item nav-link"  href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') 
}}">Logout</a>

{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```